# Regular expression - also empty string allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression... This one does not allow empty String.
How do I have to manipulate?

```
var phoneReg = new RegExp(/^\+?[0-9]+(\([0-9]+\))?[0-9-]*[0-9]$/i);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use the *"zero or one"* operator `?`, such as:

```
/^(?:regex)?$/
           ^
```

`(?:regex)` simply makes the concerned ground *uncapturable* (i.e. no need to change your `$X`, `\X` or `?X` indexes if any).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the following would work:

```
/^$|^\+?[0-9]+(\([0-9]+\))?[0-9-]*[0-9]$/i
```

I've inserted `^$|` at the beginning of your regex. The pipe (`|`) is called an "alternation" indicator and says that either the expression before it or after it must match. `^$` will simply match a string with no characters between the start and end of input. The result: an empty string or the original expression.

Comment: @user2286914 - Can you be more specific? Seems to work just fine here: http://regex101.com/r/cP2mD4

Answer (score 3):

You can put a ^$| in front which in which ^ = beginning, $ = end, | = or this other thing to the right.

```
var phoneReg = new RegExp(/^$|^\+?[0-9]+(\([0-9]+\))?[0-9-]*[0-9]$/i);
```

Comment: @user2286914 - Visual Studio's interpretation of JavaScript is not of any particular importance (and is often wrong). Have you actually tried it in the browser?